# how to remove the numbers before a word on files names

Tags: unix, centos, rename

i have this files names

dbo-101ar_thumb657.jpg door-27ar_thumb641.jpg ishq-283ar_thumb639.jpg ksm-365ar_thumb599.jpg pkyek-302_thumb604.jpg pun-68ar_thumb694.jpg

**what i'm trying to do is remove the numbers after thumb**

so must be like this

dbo-101ar_thumb.jpg door-27ar_thumb.jpg ishq-283ar_thumb.jpg ksm-365ar_thumb.jpg pkyek-302_thumb.jpg pun-68ar_thumb.jpg

**what command should i use in centos 7 ???**

Comment: what are you trying currently any research on it so far , google it and come back with something that shows efforts

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
for f in *; do 
echo $f | sed 's#[0-9]*\.#\.#g'
done
```

Will output:

```
dbo-101ar_thumb.jpg
door-27ar_thumb.jpg
ishq-283ar_thumb.jpg
ksm-365ar_thumb.jpg
pkyek-302_thumb.jpg
pun-68ar_thumb.jpg
```

If will read all the files in the current directory and later by using `sed 's#[0-9]*\.#\.#g'` it replaces numbers ending with a "." with a "."

You could also use find to prefilter your input, something like this:

```
find . -iname "*thumb*.jpg" -exec sh -c "echo {} | sed 's#[0-9]*\.#\.#g'" \;
```

It will match any file with this pattern `*thumb*.jpg` and later use sed to replace the numbers like explained before.

If you would like to `cp` or `mv` the files you could use something like:

```
find . -iname "*thumb*.jpg" -exec sh -c 'x=`echo {} | sed "s#[0-9]*\.#\.#g"`; mv {} $x' \;
```

Comment: Didn't works [root@s1 test]# find . -iname "*thumb*.jpg" -exec sh -c "echo {} | sed 's#[0-9]*\.#\.#g'" \;
./dbo-101ar_thumb.jpg
./ksm-365ar_thumb.jpg
./pun-68ar_thumb.jpg
./door-27ar_thumb.jpg
./pkyek-302_thumb.jpg
./ishq-283ar_thumb.jpg
[root@s1 test]# ls
dbo-101ar_thumb657.jpg  door-27ar_thumb641.jpg  ishq-283ar_thumb639.jpg  ksm-365ar_thumb599.jpg  pkyek-302_thumb604.jpg  pun-68ar_thumb694.jpg
[root@s1 test]#

Comment: It is printing the files like you asked (without numbers), seems you want to rename the files right?

Answer (score 0):

Look for `thumb` followed by 0 or more digits and replace it with `thumb`.

```
sed 's/thumb[0-9]*/thumb/g'
```

Or only replace when you have at least 1 digit (in this case the same result):

```
sed 's/thumb[0-9]\+/thumb/g'
```